# More Azure data requests then I can reconcile through Azure dashboard

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I recently deployed our first Azure webapp service and it was a pretty painless experience.

It was just a simple requestbin like api app to store id's fired by a webhook in to an azure data table and another end point to query if that ID is present. This is used to test the webhook in our deployment tests.

Works great, however at most I am expecting the may 60 table requests to hit the storage account a day in write and read pairs

in the last 24hr's I've received 10,23k requests (pretty consistently through the night) as well as queue and blob requests I don't have set up through the API [Screenshot of azure data account requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE4yX.png)

looking through the storage accounts audit logs I see almost exclusively list key operations with the 'Caller' column blank
[audit log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSZOd.png)

does this mean this is an internal Azure process? Some are me but I would think that was me checking through the dash

The deploy tests themselves aren't live and the DataTable only includes the two initial test entities I inserted during testing so I can't really account for these requests. Rookie mistake I'm sure but any ideas?

Bonus: I use the below block to initialise my data table. it resides in the apiClient classes constructor method on a free tier instance. Does table.createIfNotExists() count as a data transaction and does being present in constructor hammer the call as azure moves across processes on the free tier

```
_storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

_tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

table = _tableClient.GetTableReference("webhookreceipts");

// Create the table if it doesn't exist.
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

thanks

Update:

I have left it running over night again and it appears to have followed the same pattern of cycling around 500 requests per hour through the night as before

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest you click Audit log "ListKeys" to see detailed info. Please focus on the properties 'EVENT TIMESTAMP' &'CALLER' to know when triggered and who did it. Secondly, please comment all the code related with Azure table to see the result. Thirdly, please create a new Azure account to see whether have the same issues. Everything works on my side. If this issue still exist, I would suggest you contact with Azure support to get a better help.

Comment: Hey Jambor thanks for replying, So as I stated above, I've checked the Audit log for the ListKey event, the caller is blank and they are grouped in sets of 10 calls all falling on the same second. these groups are sometimes 10 minutes apart some times hours. I'll update the original question with the read and write code, but since only the expected keys are in the data table I don't think they are at fault. I'm not really keen on the last suggestion, I'm more interested in understanding where these requests come from rather then making them go away. cheers Luke

Comment: I've been pointed towards this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b19c3f7-03e6-4095-af94-dc4128d3e286/false-requests-seeing-lots-of-table-api-requests-but-no-tables-defined?forum=windowsazuredata) on the msdn forums which sounds promising aswell